# Terraform conditional attribute setting

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "instance_public_ip" {
  count               = var.assign_public_ip == "true" ? 1 : 0
  name                = "${var.name}-public-ip"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.name}-nic"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.name}-NIC-Configuration"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip.id
  }
}
```

This is my problem I only want to set public_ip_address_id attribute if the azure_rm_public_ip resource is created is this possible?

I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: What I would try is the following: `public_ip_address_id          = var.assign_public_ip ? azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip[0].id : null`, but not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would probably do is the following, since you are using the `count` meta-argument to create the `azurerm_public_ip` resource:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "instance_public_ip" {
  count               = var.assign_public_ip == "true" ? 1 : 0
  name                = "${var.name}-public-ip"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.name}-nic"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.name}-NIC-Configuration"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = var.assign_public_ip == "true" ? azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip[0].id : null
  }
}
```

Comment: This requires `assign_public_ip` to be a `bool` type (which it probably should be), but it is instead a `string` type.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it already is bool, but I'll update the answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

In a resource configuration, omitting an argument is exactly equivalent to assigning `null` to it, and so you can use a variety of strategies to write an expression that would produce `null` in some cases and a non-null value in other cases.

Here's a relatively-concise solution using a combination of [the splat operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) (the `[*]`) and [the `one` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one):

```
  public_ip_address_id = one(azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip[*].id)
```

This works in two steps:

1. The `azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip[*].id` part transforms the list of zero or one `azurerm_public_ip` objects into a list of zero or one `id` strings.
2. The `one` function has two possible outcomes depending on the result of the previous item:

   - If the result was a list containing one string, it returns that one string.
   - If the result was a list of zero strings, it returns `null`.

Due to how you've written the `count` expression for `azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip`, it isn't possible for there to be more than one element in the list passed to `one`, and so it's guaranteed to always succeed. If you were to change that `count` expression in future to potentially return a number greater than `1` then the `one` call would fail in that case, to remind you that you'll then need to revisit the definition of `public_ip_address_id` to consider what ought to happen if there is more than one IP address. However, I don't think you should worry about that until you know a good reason to have more than one IP address; I'm mentioning it only for completeness.

You might notice that what I've shown above is similar to one of the examples in the documentation for the `one` function, because this situation is common and so the `one` function is included in the Terraform language to help make it more concise to describe.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to accomplish this, but the easiest is probably with the `try` function:

```
public_ip_address_id = try(azurerm_public_ip.instance_public_ip[0].id, null)
```